# How to tell libcurl to close idle connections after a period of time?

Tags: libcurl

Is there a way to tell curl to close connections once they become idle for a certain period of time?

Comment: Did you try looking up CURLOPT_TIMEOUT?

Comment: Yes, all it does is to limit the amount of time of a request. Say I set the limit to 10s and a request takes 3s. The connection will seat idle for the remaning 7s and beyond. I'd like it to be "collected" after, say, 60s.

Comment: So, to understand right, you want that the timeout is started after the latest transmission of valid data? In this case you have to handle it on your own as described under CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 
`[...] it has limited use in dynamic use cases with varying transfer times. You are then advised [...] using CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION to implement your own timeout logic.`

Comment: As of libcurl 7.65.0 (released 2019-05-22), you can use CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN (with a default value of 118 seconds): https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.html

_If a connection is found in the cache that is older than this set maxage, it will instead be closed._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idle connections remain in the connection cache until

1. the connection is reused
2. the connection is killed because the cache needs the space
3. the cache is shut down and killed

libcurl only reuses connections the first N seconds from it was put into the pool. The default is 118 seconds and applications can change the timeout with [CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAXAGE_CONN.html).

Connections older than `MAXAGE` might remain in the pool longer because the connection age is only checked at certain occasions. It will however never be considered for reuse if older.

Comment: Is this still not implemented ? I don't understand how a connection pooling system cannot monitor the connection it pools.. Checking if a connection is not dead when the application try to use is a plus yes, (still better than having to force to close / use fresh connection for every single request) but not all. Usually we know how long the connection are kept alive in our infrastructure (ELB, Node JS servers, etc) so being able to configure it by ourselves should be the top 1 priority feature to add. Hope i'm just wrong and did not look correctly at the documentation..